# How to coerce an object into a class in R

Tags: r, class, object, coercion

I'm trying to use a new package that I've downloaded and it requires me to change my objects (matrices) to the class of the package (if I understand it correctly):

In the package manual this is written:
coerce signature(from = "matrix", to = "markovchain"): coercing to markovchain objects from matrix one

Among other things I tried using this seemed most correct based on what I've read:

```
as(from="Markov.dgf",to="markovchain",strict=TRUE,ext)
```

and I got an error:

```
Error in as(from = "Markov.dgf", to = "markovchain", strict = TRUE, ext) :
```

`unused arguments (from = "Markov.dgf", to = "markovchain")`

I would be very grateful if someone could explain whether I'm trying to do the right thing, and why I get the error. Also, I don't know if this is important in this case, but  `Markov.dgf` is actually an array of matrices rather than a single matrix.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what's the name of the package?

Comment: It's called markovchain

Comment: I think you'll find some of the [vignette's](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/markovchain/vignettes/an_introduction_to_markovchain_package.pdf) more helpful for getting started. Section 3 in particular in that one walks you directly through creating a markovchain object from a transition matrix using `new()`.

Comment: also, the examples included in help provides a good guide as well:https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/markovchain/versions/0.6.9.10/topics/markovchain-class

Comment: Thanks for the link, I managed to figure it out with it!

Answer (score 0):

The reason the code `as(from="Markov.dgf",to="markovchain",strict=TRUE,ext)` does not work is that the "Markov.dgf", as you pointed out, is not a matrix object, but it belongs to another R class. Actually coerce methods have been written only for specific classes in the markovchain package. If you use objects like "Markov.dgf" frequently, you might consider writing a coerce - method from yourself. You can give a glance to the classesAndMethod.R file in the code forlder of the package source to find sensible example of coerce methods at this regard.